# How did they swim below the sea without any gear in The Abyss?

Tags: the-abyss

In the movie *[The Abyss](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096754/)*, Virgil and Catfish [had to swim](https://vhistory.files.wordpress.com/2018/06/long-swim.jpg) (without gear) to get to a hatch to open a gate. But, if I recall correctly, they're 2000 feet below the surface.

How did they do that? I thought it was not possible to do this without wearing pressurized suits.

Comment: Sometimes you see Deep sea divers in a Hard Shell Suit. This is to allow them to be at normal atmosphere pressure in the suit. (So they will not need to decompress when they return to the surface.) BUT if your diving in a wetsuit type suit, your breathing pressurized air, so your body has the same pressure inside (air) and outside (water). Since they were already in an pressurized vessel, they did not need a pressure suit. They only would need protection from the cold, and an air supply. IIRC none of the suits they used in the movie were Hard Shell Suits (aka Atmospheric diving suit.)

Comment: Is there even any pressure in the ocean that can kill people?

Comment: @theonlygusti No offence, but have you been living under a rock for the past week? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Titan_submersible_incident

Comment: @theonlygusti Exactly. The only way pressure could increase as you descend *is if the earth is round*.   And what are the chances of that?

Comment: @F1Krazy They died because of the sudden increase in pressure, not the pressure itself.

Comment: @theonlygusti Human bodies contain empty cavities inside such as lungs, throat, digestive system, etc. Also your diaphragm needs to be able overcome external pressure so you can breath. Your heart also has to overcome pressure  to pump blood in your veins as external pressure tries to squeeze inwards. So at some pressure, you're going to get crushed just like a submarine. The biology of deep sea animals doesn't contain such cavities.

Comment: @DKNguyen normally divers fill the lung/throat cavities with something equally pressured so they don't collapse. My curiosity was about, whether the pressure that actually outright kills a human is even reached at the bottom of the Mariana trench?

Comment: @theonlygusti You can't fill all cavities in the human body though because the human body isn't built that way. Even for cavities that you theoretically have external access to, such as your with your stomach or intestines, you aren't going to be able to fill them.

Comment: @DKNguyen I don't think you will die if the air in your intestines is compressed

Comment: @theonlygusti: But you will if your entire intestinal cavity is compressed to the point that it liquifies. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LEY3fN4N3D8

Comment: @theonlygusti Even ignoring the fact that the structures in your body can be compressed even if there is no empty space inside them, when when your intestines compress they leave behind volume to be filled in with other parts of your body, ad so on.

Comment: There’s a lot of confusion in the comments here. Some things to note: in *The Abyss*, most of the movie, including the scene in question, does not take place at the bottom of the Mariana Trench, it takes place thousands of feet closer to the surface on the rim of the trench. As humans not in a pressure vessel dive, our bodies gradually equalize to the pressure we dive to, but there can be consequences. If you recall, when Lindsey and the soldiers arrive at the rig they have to spend like 8-12 hours adjusting their bodies to the increased pressure.

Comment: There’s something wrong even in my own comment. The setting is the rim of the **Cayman Trough** in the Caribbean, not the Mariana Trench in the Atlantic.

Comment: @MooingDuck that's not an experiment relevant to the question I had. The depth of that experiment is only 100m (according to the comments). Humans have survived free-diving to 253m, scuba diving (also has no pressure protection) to 332.5m, etc. That experiment is probably not representative because the suit has air in it and because they pressurise it as fast as they can.

Comment: @DKNguyen as far as I can find out, a single kidney already has more volume than the highest volume of air ever normally found in the intestines. I've read before that the organs of the human body are great at reshuffling and you never even notice (e.g. after appendoctomies) and that seems to be true

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Saturation diving](https://dan.org/alert-diver/article/saturation-diving/#:%7E:text=In%201992%20Comex%2C%20a%20French,(71.1%20atmospheres)%20to%20date.) is a real technique that allows divers to work at very great depths. The deepest dive recorded (with heated suits and scuba gear) was over 2100 feet, almost exactly equivalent to what's seen in the film.

> In 1992 Comex, a French diving company, conducted a series of
> experimental dives to 2,133 feet (650 meters) of seawater in a
> hyperbaric research chamber in France. For two hours one diver went to
> 2,300 feet (701 meters), which is the deepest a human has gone under
> pressure (71.1 atmospheres) to date.

This also tallies with what's described in the film's [novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/40289). The Deepcore is under a huge amount of air pressure, along with the crew inside. This allows them to work in the pressurised water without needing to decompress when coming back into the underwater platform.

> That's what Deepcore meant to Bud. Going down into the water. Going
> deep, living there with all that pressure inside you, all around you,
> **all those thirty or forty or fifty atmospheres poking and prying right
> there in your lungs, in your blood, in every cell of your body** - but
> you're breathing, you're alive, and when it's all done, you come up
> and feel the sunlight on you and you won again. No contest.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Abyss: A Novel](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/40289)</sup></sub>

Comment: We see Lindsey and the SEALs enter a compression chamber when they arrive on Deepcore - presumably to help them saturate and acclimate to the pressure.

Comment: IIRC, similar technology is used in the Michael Crichton novel *Sphere*, which was roughly contemporary and which I frequently conflate with this movie.

Comment: Also see this question: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32640/what-is-the-maximum-atmospheric-pressure-a-human-can-tolerate

Comment: They also reference this at the end of the movie when the station is carried to the surface and one of the crew points out that they should be dead after such a rapid rise (to a reply of "[the aliens] did something to us" to prevent this).

Answer (score 6):

I am not entirely sure which part of the film you mean, but at one point Virgil/Bud does venture out of the craft without a pressurised suit.  he is shown filling his lungs with fluid in order to be able to breathe, but obviously this is less convenient and pleasant than taking a mix of gases.

The actual fluid depicted in the film, oxygenated perfluorocarbon, was shown being used on a mouse earlier in the film, and the scene with the mouse was filmed without the use of special effects.  It was not possible to use on humans at that time, but it was hoped that the technology would become usable in that way. [Source](https://filmschoolrejects.com/the-abyss-breathing-fluid/)

The benefit of filling one's lungs with liquid is that many of the difficulties of deep sea diving flow from the pressure differential between air and water interfering with the breathing process.  With liquid in the lungs, the body tissues would not become saturated with nitrogen in the same way.  At least that's the theory, but I don't believe it's been successfully used for humans yet.

So in theory, it might be possible to dive without heavy suits in pressurised depths using liquid breathing, but not yet.

More information is available on Wikipedia. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_breathing#Diving)

Comment: That's an entirely different part of the film where goes much *much* deeper.

Comment: Just like Valorum mentioned, that's not the part that i wonder. In the part that i mentioned, they just swim nakedly without any gear whatsoever. It's around 1:39:50 in the extended version.

Comment: I'm at a loss why people are upvoting this entirely incorrect answer

Comment: @Valorum - probably because it sounds good, referenced something in the film, and something scientific.

Comment: Was this written by a robot that didn't see the film?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri No, it references a different part of the same film. No need to be insulting.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri I think it's more likely that it was written by someone who saw the movie when it came out, and doesn't have perfect memory of something they saw nearly  THIRTY FIVE YEARS AGO. (Wow, I didn't realize until I looked it up that it was that long ago. Seemed like a nineties movie, but it was actually released in 1989.)

Comment: @Corey: GPT LLM API's have no feelings and are not sensitive to insult.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri You know what else GPT doesn't do? Make spelling mistakes. Or miss capitalisation at the start of sentences. Your assumptions are flawed and you're just compounding the issue. Why the hate?